# Limit of a Piecewise Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose we define a sequence, $a_k$, by 
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 e^{-\frac{k}{2}} \ \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
0 \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, say that we want to take its limit as $k \to \infty$. My question mainly relates to how we work with $x$. It seems that the limit would depend on the value of $x$, or at the very least we would have two cases to consider. If I'm not mistaken, both are zero, so it seems reasonable to conclude that the limit is $0$. Is this the correct line of thinking? Is there a better way to formalize such an argument?

Thanks.

EDIT: Per a very helpful comment from Bungo, let's consider one alternate case where $x$ is not solely a constant. Say, for example, we define a sequence by
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 e^{-\frac{kx}{2}} \ \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
0 \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
In this alternate case, would we proceed differently?

Comment: I came up with an example off the top of my head, but this does sound like a very important distinction. Would you mind commenting on the case you mentioned where $x$ is part of a term that isn't constant?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the limit will again be a function of $x$, so in general your answer will involve $x$.  For example, the limit as $k$ goes to infinity of $f_k(x)=x^2+x/k$ is $f(x)=x^2$.  In your care, the limit is the constant function $0$.  In general, one is often concerned with additional properties of the sequence of functions and not just the "pointwise" limit.  For example, is the convergence uniform in $x$?  (If not, then $f$ may fail to be continuous even if all the $f_k$ are continuous.)  Or is the convergent sequence dominated by an $L^1$ function so that you can apply the dominated convergence theorem to its integral?